# Connect to serial device

Tags: c++, serial-port, vala

I'm trying to write bytes to an serialport, where I connect a relay.
Everything works fine, if I use C++ for this: (comments are german, sorry)

```
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <termios.h>

RelayProtocol::RelayProtocol()
{
    // Create structure
    struct termios options;

    // Open Connection
    _handle = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    // clear all flags
    fcntl(_handle, F_SETFL, 0);

    // Get current options
    tcgetattr(_handle, &options);

    // Set Boundrate (19200)
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200); // Input
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200); // Output

    // Set serial-flags
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; 
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; 
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    options.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0; 
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10; 

    // Flush settings
    tcflush(_handle,TCIOFLUSH);

    tcsetattr(_handle, TCSAFLUSH, &options);

    fcntl(_handle, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    fcntl(_handle, F_SETFL, 0);

    // Initialize relay
    SendCommand(1, 1, 0);
}
```

Now I tried the same using vala:

```
 public static void main (string[] args) {
        int handle = Posix.open ("/dev/ttyUSB0", Posix.O_RDWR | Posix.O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

        Posix.termios termios;

        Posix.fcntl (handle, Posix.F_SETFL, 0);

        Posix.tcgetattr (handle, out termios);


        termios.c_ispeed = 19200;
        termios.c_ospeed = 19200;

        /* Configure serialport */
        termios.c_cflag &= ~Posix.PARENB; 
        termios.c_cflag &= ~Posix.CSTOPB; 
        termios.c_cflag &= ~Posix.CSIZE; 
        termios.c_cflag |= Posix.CS8;
        termios.c_cflag |= (Posix.CLOCAL | Posix.CREAD);

        termios.c_lflag &= ~(Posix.ICANON | Posix.ECHO | Posix.ECHOE | Posix.ISIG);
        termios.c_oflag &= ~Posix.OPOST; 

        termios.c_cc[Posix.VMIN] = 0;
        termios.c_cc[Posix.VTIME] = 10;

        Posix.tcflush (handle, Posix.TCIOFLUSH);

        Posix.tcsetattr (handle, Posix.TCSAFLUSH, termios);

        Posix.fcntl (handle, Posix.F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
        Posix.fcntl (handle, Posix.F_SETFL, 0);

        /* Everything works fine, if I open it using tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0*/
        uint8[] data = new uint8[4];
        data[0] = 1;
        data[1] = 1;
        data[2] = 0;
        data[3] = data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[2];

        int l = (int)Posix.write (handle, data, data.length);

        Thread.usleep (1000 * 1000);

        data[0] = make_array (2, true)[0];
        data[1] = make_array (2, true)[1];
        data[2] = make_array (2, true)[2];
        data[3] = data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[2];

        l = (int)Posix.write (handle, data, data.length);
    }
```

I have created two variables on the top, which doesn't exist in the posix namespace. I simply print the value in C.
This code in vala doesn't work, the relay doesn't receive anything, although it uses the same flags and handles.
The strange thing is, that the vala code works fine, if I open a terminal and run "tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0".
It seems that the valacode isn't able to initialize the serial port, so relay will never receive them.

Anybody know a fix for this, or find my mistake in the vala code?
Normally the librarys should be the same in both programming languages.

Comment: _"(comments are german, sorry)"_ Translate them for the question. Clearly you are capable of very good English. So it is purely a matter of effort.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Is this C++?  The syntax for `main` is not correct for C++.

Comment: The second one is Vala :)

Comment: You could have a look at `l` to see the number of bytes transferred and if it is `-1` then look at `Posix.errno` for an idea of what went wrong - see [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html)

Comment: It prints the expected bytrs

Comment: OK, well all sounds fine. It could just be a typo in your baud rate. Why are you not using Posix.B19200, the same as your C++ program?

Comment: It seems the question is about Vala and not C++, so the C++ tag doesn't seem appropriate.